# How to get only uniq column values from a line using linux or perl?

Tags: perl, unique

I have a file like below

```
1 B B C D B
2 K B D D K
1 B B C D B
2 K B D D K
1 B B C D B
2 K B D D K
```

I want the output to look like this

```
1 B C D
2 K B D
1 B C D
2 K B D
1 B C D
2 K B D
```

Sort commands don't work, so I tried writing a Perl program -

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper; 

my $file1 = <$ARGV[0]>;

open (IF2, "$file1") || die "Cannot open the file\n";

open (OUT, ">$file1.out") || die "Cannot open the out file\n";



my $k = 0;my $i=0;
my @line;
my $m;
my @line2;



while ( chomp($m = <IF2>) ) {   
    my $count = 0;
    @line2 = split(/\t/,$m);#<stdin>;
    my $l = length @line2;print $l;<stdin>;
    for (my $x = 0; $x < $l;$x++) {
        my $k = 0;
        for (my $y = 0;$y < $l; $y) {
             $i++;
    #       
            if ($count == 0) 
            {
                print OUT "\t$line2[$x]";
                $count++;
            }

            if ($count != 0 && $x != $y)
            {
                if ($line2[$x] eq $line2[$y])
                {
                     $k++;
                }

            }
        }
        if ($k == 0)
        {
            print OUT "\t$line2[$x]";
        }
    }
  print OUT "\n";   
  }



  print $i;

  close IF2;
  close OUT;
```

But it didn't work.
Can some one help?

Comment: This is very, very complicated.  You have Perl at your disposal, with a myriad of ways to process text, so write Perl, not C.  As you read the line, [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) it, then pass that list through `uniq` from [List::Utils](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.416/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm) module

Comment: Wait ... you don't want "_uniq_" elements -- your output has multiple `B`s, `D`s etc.  You only want to remove _adjacent_ duplicates, correct?  If so, my comment above is not right, `uniq` will leave only one `B`, one `D`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

**Note** The input and output examples in the question were edited: now the data is consistent with the title, asking to remove all duplicates. (See the original question for how it looked.) I am leaving the answer to the original question as well, until we hear from the poster.

---

I would like to make a general remark first.

Your posted code is an honest attempt to write a C-style program in Perl. I recommend to resist that and to learn how to *use Perl* instead. It does take a little investment of time and effort but it goes quick and pays off quick. As you can see below, it makes many things incomparably easier.

Even so, there are   issues with the posted code but I can't write a code review now.

**Edited question**

We need to remove all duplicates from each line. One way: split the line by whitespace then remove duplicates from the list, which is a standard task with ready solutions.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my $file = '...';
my $fileout = '...';

open my $fh,     '<', $filen   or die "Can't open $file: $!";
open my $fh_out, '>', $fileout or die "Can't open $fileout: $!";

while (<$fh>) 
{
    my @unique = uniq split;
    print $fh_out "@unique\n";
}
close $fh;
close $fh_out;
```

The line with spaces is restored by printing the quoted array, when spaces (or whatever is in [`$"`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables)) are inserted between elements . The other option is to [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) the resulting list

```
my $res = join ' ', uniq split;
print $fh_out $res, "\n";
```

or just   `print $fh_out join(' ', uniq split), "\n";`.

This uses `uniq` from [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.416/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm#) module. Note from [`uniq`](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.416/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm#uniq_LIST) that

> The order of elements in the returned list is the same as in LIST.

Once `List::MoreUtils` got mentioned, take note of the core module [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) as well.

A one-liner version

```
perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -lne'print join " ", uniq split' input > output
```

or

```
perl -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -lane'print join " ", uniq @F' input > output
```

See [Command switches in perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

---

**Original question (see it in the edit history)**

I was answering the question with the belief that this was the input

```
1 B B C D B 2 K B D D K 1 B B C D B 2 K B D D K 1 B B C D B 2 K B D D K
```

and this was the desired output

```
1 B C D 2 K B D 1 B C D 2 K B D 1 B C D 2 K B D
```

---

By your desired output you want to remove only *adjacent* duplicates (not get "*uniq*" as the title says).

For that you can use the ability of regex to match repeated patterns, by using [backreferences](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backreferences).  First we need to strip all spaces, and we'll put them back in the end. For example

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = '...';
my $fileout = '...';

open my $fh,     '<', $filen   or die "Can't open $file: $!";
open my $fh_out, '>', $fileout or die "Can't open $fileout: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) 
{
    $line =~ s/\s*//g;       # remove spaces  /
    $line =~ s/(.)\1+/$1/g;  # remove adjacent duplicates
    $line =~ s/(.)/$1 /g;    # restore space
    print $fh_out $line;
}
close $fh;
close $fh_out;
```

The `.` matches any character, replace it with something more restrictive if needed (for example `\w`, for a "word" character).  See [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html). Note that we cannot restore space along with replacement (like `s/(.)\1+/$1 /g`) since non-repeating chars aren't matched and don't get the space back.

This can be done in more concise ways.

---

A one-liner version

```
perl -pe's/\s*//g; s/(.)\1+/$1/g; s/(.)/$1 /g' input > output
```

See [Command switches in perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: The suggested one-liner doesn't work for me (perl 5.18), returns a single line without duplicates properly collapsed ('1 B C D B 2 K B D K 1 B C D B 2 K B D K 1 B C D B 2 K B D K'), plz check

Comment: *"By your desired output you want to remove only adjacent duplicates"* I don't think so. `1 B B C D B` is reduced to `1 B C D`, so all `B` characters after the first are removed, regardless of whether they are adjacent.

Comment: @Borodin  Yes, after you edited the question to break that one line into multiple ones.  The original question had one long line and I didn't expect that it should be multiple lines. Is that the reason for the downvote? That the question got rewritten, and now this answer appears invalid?

Comment: @ffeast  You are looking into a changed question.  Click on "Edited" to see previous edits -- one line of input and one line of output were shown, which I considered to be a representative lines, of input and output.  This post answers _that_ question.

Comment: @ffeast I have now added an answer to _this_ question as well.  (While this may have been intended by the poster, it was by no means obvious. They did originally post one line of input and one line of output, which did have repeated characters thus indicated the desire to remove adjacent dupes only.  Which is harder, btw.)

Comment: @zdim: The separate lines were the OP' s original intent. If you look at the edit history you will see that the data was always on separate lines but they had omitted the necessary markdown to display it properly and it all flowed into one line. It was "I have a file like below" that gave me the clue to look at the question's source. The data did not appear "below" and I suspected just this error. I'm sorry if my edit confused you. I have no idea about the downvote.

Comment: @Borodin  I see this now, when I go to "edit" in the revision history. (Good call, to look at that.) Your edit came after my post and I only saw it the next day.  What confused me was the comment, since I thought that you would know what I was answering since you edited the question, which originally appeared with the single line of input and output  (indicating the removal of adjacent repetitions only -- what I also stated in the answer.) As for the downvote, after the edit I guess that my answer indeed looked awkward (and wrong).  But before it, it didn't, with +2

Answer (score 2):

I suggest something like this. It finds all occurrences of whitespace followed by non-whitespace, and checks whether the non-whitespace has been seen before on the current line. The matched substring is deleted if the non-whitespace has been seen before, otherwise it is left untouched

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my %seen;
    s/(\s+(\S+))/ $seen{$2}++ ? '' : $1 /eg;
    print;
}

__DATA__
1 B B C D B
2 K B D D K
1 B B C D B
2 K B D D K
1 B B C D B
2 K B D D K
```

#### output

```
1 B C D
2 K B D
1 B C D
2 K B D
1 B C D
2 K B D
```

This may be done in a one-liner like this

```
perl -pe 'my %s; s/(\s+(\S+))/ $s{$2}++ ? "" : $1 /eg' myfile
```

Comment: This one-liner also gives a wrong result: perl -pe 's/(\s+(\S+))/ $seen{$2}++ ? "" : $1 /eg' input.txt: "1 B C D
2 K
1
2
1
2
"

Comment: @ffeast: Fixed.